# restore last session of my text editor

Tags: macos, text-editor

I am looking for text editor which can reopen all my saved/unsaved tabs that was there in the last session before my mac got restarted or text editor got closed unexpectedly.

I always have my text editor open in any of my desktops in mac but if for some reason I need to reboot or text editor gets closed unexpectedly, then if I restart my mac or reopen text editor then it should bring back all windows that was opened in last session whether saved or unsaved.

I tried with Sublime but looks like it didn't work for me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**TextEdit**, which is part of every version of MacOS, does exactly that, if you check this box when shutting down or logging out.

[image]

The downside is trying to discipline yourself to put things away once in a while.  At this moment, I literally¹ have three dozen "Untitled" text windows in my Dock.

¹The pre-2000 meaning of "literally"

Comment: RE: "At this moment, I literally¹ have three dozen "Untitled" text windows in my Dock" -- Did you know that you can have an app's windows minimized into the application's icon on the **Dock**? --  **System Preferences** > **Dock** > **[√] Minimize windows into application icon**

Comment: Yes.  I also suspect that it makes them harder to find.

Comment: Not really as you have the list on the Window menu or the list on the Dock tile with a right-click.

Comment: I've never fully tested this, but I have a feeling that System Prefs>General> 'Ask to keep changes when closing documents' & 'Close windows when quitting an app' may need to be unchecked too.

Comment: I have seen the “list on the dock tile” and I don’t think it would be practical with more than three dozen items.  Plus, when they’re somewhat hidden, there’s even less motivation to clean up.

Comment: I do not have “Ask” unchecked, and it still saves all of the machine crashes.  “Reopen windows” treats each document as NOT being closed, so “ask” doesn’t apply.  Not sure about the other.